# How to turn off lines in raster fill label mixed legends ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, line, legend, raster, spatial

I'm plotting points and two sets of spatial lines (roads and rivers) on top of a categorical raster. I can define the colors and labels of the rasters and give that legend a title and it looks great. But when I add the spatial lines on top and try to add a second legend for the two sets of spatial lines, black lines are now introduced into the raster category boxes. How do I remove these lines?

```
colors_6 =
  c("darkolivegreen1", # Crop
    "#FDE333", # Open Canopy
    "#CCAA50", # Barren/fallow
    "cadetblue1", # Water
    "#A4A4A4", # Developed
    "#0A6B22") # Closed Canopy

ggplot(my_raster)+
 geom_spatraster(data = my_raster, aes(fill = Classes))+
 geom_point(data = the_points, aes(x = X, y = Y))+
 scale_fill_manual(values = colors_6,
                   labels = c("Crop", "Open Canopy", "Barren/Fallow",
                              "Water", "Developed", "Closed Canopy")+
 geom_sf(data = roads, aes(color = "Roads"), alpha = 0.5, show.legend = 'line')+
 geom_sf(data = rivers, aes(color = "Rivers"), alpha = 0.5, show.legend = 'line')+
 scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("Roads" = "black", "Flowlines" = "blue")
```

[image]

I also tried defining the categorical raster legend with scale_fill_discrete() and the lines with scale_color_discrete(). I tried using inherit.aes = FALSE and creating new scales with ggnewscale::new_scale_color and new_scale_fill but it doesn't work.

Thanks/

Answer (score 0):

I swear it's always two seconds after I breakdown and actually post a question that I figure out the problem I've been mulling over for twelve hours:

Here's how I fixed it, specify the key_glyph.

```
    colors_6 = c("darkolivegreen1", # Crop
                 "#FDE333", # Open Canopy
                 "#CCAA50", # Barren/fallow
                 "cadetblue1", # Water
                 "#A4A4A4", # Developed
                 "#0A6B22") # Closed Canopy
     ggplot(my_raster)+
        geom_spatraster(data = my_raster, aes(fill = Classes), 
                        key_glyph = "rect")+
        geom_point(data = the_points, aes(x = X, y = Y))+
        scale_fill_manual(values = colors_6,
                          labels = c("Crop", "Open Canopy", "Barren/Fallow",
                                     "Water", "Developed", "Closed Canopy")+
        geom_sf(data = roads, aes(color = "Roads"), alpha = 0.5, key_glyph = 
                "smooth")+
        geom_sf(data = rivers, aes(color = "Rivers"), alpha = 0.5, key_glyph = 
                "smooth")+
        scale_color_manual(name = "", 
                          values = c("Roads" = "black", "Flowlines" = "blue"))
```